# Error installing Aircrack in Termux (E: Unable to locate package aircrack-ng)

Tags: applications, installation, termux

An error is occurring when I try to install aircrack-ng in Termux.
**E: Unable to locate package aircrack-ng**

When I try to use `apt` or `pkg` to search for aircrack, it doesn't find anything either. Here are the outputs:

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39Oqx.jpg)

```
~ $ pkg install aircrack-ng
Checking availability of current mirror:
[*] https://packages-cf.termux.dev/apt/termux-main: ok
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package aircrack-ng
~ $ apt install aircrack-ng
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package aircrack-ng
~ $
```

[When I search for the package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwmbn.jpg)

```
~ $ pkg search aircrack-ng
Checking availability of current mirror:
[*] https://packages-cf.termux.dev/apt/termux-main: ok
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
~ $ apt search aircrack
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
~ $ apt search aircrack-ng
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
~ $
```

I thought it wasn't finding the package, so I decided to use `git` to clone the aircrack repository on GitHub and install from there, but I don't even know if there's a way to do that or how to do it.

Note: I'm quite a beginner so I apologize if something doesn't make sense.

Comment: May be NetHunter (Kali) for Android would be an easier start for you. It should already contain tools like aircrack.

Answer (score 0):

You first need the repository that has aircrack-ng

```
apt install root-repo
```

Then do

```
apt install aircrack-ng -y
```

[More on this here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-aircrack-ng-in-termux/)

---

However, I would suggest you to install aircrack on linux running on termux. There are many apps to achieve this but I personally use [AnLinux](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/exa.lnx.a/)

Being a beginner is not bad.. we all start somewhere :)